# Guestbook example app fails to pass moderate load test

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I had performance issues with flexible app engine service that I wrote in Python. So I decided to conduct load tests on different languages and environments and this is what I found. 
Somehow autoscaler on flexible app engine won't work on Python! We are considering rewriting our service in another language! Can somebody explain how the performance can be so bad on a guestbook application in Python? I was expecting horizontal autoscaler to just WORK every time!

[image: load test results]

Comment: Maybe show the code and explain the test details?

Comment: Code is same as this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/datastore) I conducted a load test using locust with 25 users hatching at 1 users per second. As soon as it gets around 10 users, it starts to fail the incoming requests. 
In the log I see 502 errors in the load balancer. If I manually increase the number of instances from 2 to let's say 20, it can handle more users(100 users), but this is a band-aid fix!